# Exclude specific words in search

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

I've tried using the - (not) symbol in searches on Stack Overflow to reduce the number of irrelevant matches in the results, with no effect.

I'm getting really sick of "Whats your favorite programmer joke / cartoon?" appearing in the results for almost every search I perform.

I've read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/search) and there is no mention of how to use a Not operator to exclude the following word.

I've heard about excluding tags using -, but I'm talking about excluding words.

Is this possible?  Has it just not been implemented?  If not, I'd really like to see this added to search.

Comment: Arbitrary logical expressions is the more general question.

Answer (score 12):

This was added a while back - you *can* now use the - operator to exclude search terms: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what%27s+your+favorite+programmer+-cartoon

Comment: Yes, Google is always a good backup.  I've developed a few searches in my time and usually found implementing the NOT operator pretty easy.  Strange it isn't already  available.

Comment: The link in Shog9's answer does not use the `site:` operator. You might consider using something like `site:stackoverflow.com` to constrain your Google search to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @chb: thanks for the heads-up: this was actually implemented a while ago.

Comment: @Shog9 *facepalm* I had no idea; should've looked at the post date and tried again.

Comment: Your search tips, like the steak ones at Tumbleweeds, are out of date then