# How do I combine/exclude multiple tags from a search?

Tags: discussion, tags, search

I want to search for several related tags at once. When I type multiple tag-names in the search box, only one gets selected and I have to sift through a horde of non-pertinent questions.

E.g. 1: I want to find all questions where 'java' AND 'netbeans' AND 'tomcat' all are defined per question.

E.g. 2: (this may be a bit much to hope for) I want to find all questions where 'java' AND 'netbeans' BUT_NOT 'tomcat' is defined.

Alternatively, is there a way to search through the previous search results?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Indeed it is possible.
This brings up all questions tagged with all three:

> [search: [java] [netbeans] [tomcat]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+[netbeans]+[tomcat])

This brings up all questions tagged with **`[java]`** and **`[netbeans]`** but not **`[tomcat]`**:

> [search: -[tomcat] [java] [netbeans]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[-tomcat]+[java]+[netbeans])

Comment: Thanks - I should have asked this question long ago. Maybe this info should be added to the FAQ?

Comment: Are you sure Jeff? Or is it just **Opera** that means that you need to put the minus inside of the square brackets? (Another angel dies.)

Answer (score 2):

`random`'s answer covers your question,
there is one more way to search -- the Google way [as described for this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19253/exclude-specific-words-in-stackoverflow-search).

If you sift through the '**Related**' questions on the right for this question,
there are a lot of other things you can do to search here.

Here is one more reference on [additional search features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1114/additional-search-features-syntax).