# How do I select multiple tags at Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, tags, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I combine/exclude multiple tags from a search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24514/how-do-i-combine-exclude-multiple-tags-from-a-search)

How do I select multiple tags to search with?

For instance "logging" and "enterprise library"?

Comment: Should be on Meta

Answer (score 1):

Check this page for information: https://stackoverflow.com/search