# How do I exclude a tag from my "URL bookmark"?

Tags: support, tags, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I combine/exclude multiple tags from a search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24514/how-do-i-combine-exclude-multiple-tags-from-a-search)

I use the following URL to look up Google Maps questions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps+or+google-maps-api-3

However, I often see Android questions, which I am not familiar with, and wish to exclude it from the list of questions that appear.

I tried adding `+not+android` to my URL but it has no effect.

I wish to reconstruct the URL, preferably avoiding to use the search box.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps+google-maps-api-3+-android

It also looks like the keyword "or" is unnecessary.

Comment: can't believe that it was this straightforward.

Comment: how did you done that, "about me" mirror effect in profile ?

Comment: @Lucifer MS paint and print screen

Comment: ha ha,,,,, how i haven't thought of it...very easy one, i thought it is some script kind of stuff, anyways thanks