# Does it make sense to add tags retroactively?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I was just adding the tag [[ng-grid]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ng-grid/info) retroactively to some older Stack Overflow posts, until I noticed all Stack Overflow posts older than April 2013 about ng-grid didn't have that tag... *Probably the tag was only created around that time.* 

And it turns out to be true. According to the [[ng-grid] revision link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16276331/revisions) it was created on the 29th April 2013.

Does it **make sense to retag older Stack Overflow questions retroactively once a new tag is created?**

- Does it help in linking new questions?

- Does it help users in finding the question through Stack Overflow's search?

- ...

BTW, these are the posts I suggested a retag for, but there are still more...:

- [15647981](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647981/angularjs-and-ng-grid-auto-save-data-to-the-server-after-a-cell-was-changed)
- [15120188](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120188/get-ajax-data-into-angular-grid)
- [16015088](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015088/how-to-set-aggregation-with-grouping-in-ng-grid)

Comment: Just a note: Don't go by the revision link. That's not always accurate. That timestamp is when the *tag wiki* was created, not when the *tag* was created.

Comment: @animuson Is there another way we can see when a tag is created?

Comment: No, only employees have access to that information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it does. When I'm looking for something and I know there is a tag for it, I want to simply type [something] in search window and I don't expect to miss some questions on that topic due to them being too old to be properly tagged.

Comment: Thanks you for the response. What would the best / fastest way to retag? Thanks to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24514 I now know that you can search on <pre>nggrid -[ng-grid]</pre> or <pre>nggrid -[ng-grid]</pre> to find posts that probably need a retag (no batch possible as some only mention it). There used to be a "retag" option but now I only see "share" | "edit" | "flag" at the button of each question?

Comment: @AardVark71 retag [has been dealt with](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186373/225745) as it [was no longer needed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182586/225745) - now you simply retag in edit window.

Answer (score 4):

Sure.

It can also make sense to update a question which has answers that are no longer valid on current versions of the software. For example, asking how to list all the tables in SQL Server 2000 would likely be tagged [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) and would have answers that use `sysobjects` - while these still work in modern versions, they're not the preferred approach (and modern answers won't work on SQL Server 2000). So I would re-tag such a question [sql-server-2000](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2000).