# Excluding tags in new navigation

Tags: feature-request, new-nav

In the old navigation, I could search JavaScript questions while excluding jQuery like this:

```
[javascript] -[jquery]
```

This doesn't work in the new navigation.

Could this functionality be added?

Here are related questions, but the accepted answers no longer work:

[How do I combine/exclude multiple tags from a search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24514/how-do-i-combine-exclude-multiple-tags-from-a-search)

[How to search for questions not containing a certain tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271236/how-to-search-questions-not-containing-certain-tag)

---

**Update:**  [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259916/281674) provides a work-around, but I'm hoping this can be default functionality.

Comment: I'm okay with this being closed, but your answer to the other question provides a work-around (which is great!), while my post is a request this this be a default feature of the new navigation.