# Hard to exclude tags in search for new nav

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search, new-nav

Before the new nav, it was possible to use the search box to require some tags and exclude others.  Typing something like `[included-tag] -[excluded-tag]` would bring up results that included and excluded the respective tags.  Here's an [example on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-request+-phrase-request), which was made with the search `[word-request] -[phrase-request]`.

In the new nav, typing *only tags* in the search area ignores the `-` modifier.  So typing `[master] -[slave]` is somehow reinterpreted into `[master] [slave]` (notice the negation `-` is now gone).  In order to work around this, I have to include some extra non-tag search criteria.  A search like `[master] -[slave] is:question` [seems to work](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaster%5D%20-%5Bslave%5D%20is%3Aquestion) as intended.  But if you remove the `is:question` from the search box (or the url) [it fails](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaster%5D%20-%5Bslave%5D) to handle the tags properly.

Please fix the new tag behavior to support the old tag-exclusion behavior without having to resort to weird workarounds.

This question is a more detailed version of this [related feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259473/excluding-tags-in-new-navigation).

Comment: I think I'm seeing this, also. I'm trying to use advanced search to exclude certain tags.  For example, say I want all question *not* tagged elephant.  The help suggests that '-[elephant]' should work, but that appears instead to find all stories that *include* the phrase elephant but are not tagged elephant.

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, seems that the new nav search simply doesn't function correctly, I've noticed that too. What do we do, until it's fixed? Choose some ugly workarounds (unfortunately) that will lead us to the "old search engines", like this:

```
[android]-[java] is:
```

[It will show](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D-%5Bjava%5D+is%3A)  the results you want, including both questions and answers.

> [image]

And if you want only questions, `is:question` is too long anyway :) Use `is:q`.

Comment: Yeah, I've had to resort to this.  Although, since I'm usually searching for questions, `is:question` is what I usually use.

Comment: @rya in this case, `is:q` is shorter :)

Answer (score 6):

With the latest iteration, excluded tags are now differently broken.

On [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), I want to see posts that have the [c#] tag but not the [.net] tag. Should be easy, right? Type `[c#] -[.net]` in the search box.

But no. I'm using the [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav).

I get directed to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive&tags=-.net%20c%23&mode=any). Funny, I thought there'd be more hits.

[image: 0 questions tagged <code>-[.net] [c#]</code>]

But wait...

[image: 5 questions with new activity]

The new questions tagged [c#] but not [.net] are getting fed correctly!

That's not all. I click “Reload”. I get redirected to [this other page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive&tags=.net%20c%23&mode=any) — questions tagged [c#] or [.net]. And the search box now contains `[.net] [c#]`. Somehow reloading the page dropped that `-` in front of `.net` in the URL.