# Search `-[sometag]` broken in beta UI

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-nav

I used to search for `[dart-polymer] -[dart]`. In the search box this is automatically changed to `-[dart] [dart-polymer]` [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive&tags=-dart%20dart-polymer&mode=any) which is invalid AFAIR because a search must not start with -. The bar containing the `all` and `any` buttons shows on the left `not [dart] [dart-polymer]` (I get no search results but I'm sure there are related questions). When I switch to `all` [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive&tags=-dart%20dart-polymer&mode=all) it shows `[dart] [polymer-dart]` (where the search results have the `[dart]` and `[dart-polymer]` tag) which is not at all what I wanted.

I added the URL created by these actions as `example` links, but the links don't show the same result as I get when I execute the explained steps.

Comment: Works fine for me. [Like here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based+-biology) which was the result from searching `[science-based] -[biology]` on [worldbuilding.se]. A specific example with a link to the resultant search page might be useful.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Your example works for me too but here it stays on the old UI version. I added links and additional explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

1. search is redirecting you to the home page with a negative filter
2. negative filters are not supported in the new navigation

Point 1 is a bug (and is reported elsewhere); point 2 is a new feature (which we are considering). I'm using this question as a placeholder for that.

Comment: Is there a workaround for 2 until this is implemented?

Comment: Reminder: this is a new manifestation of an old bug — http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259915/hard-to-exclude-tags-in-search-for-new-nav/261422#261422