# Is there a way to filter certain tags?

Tags: support, tags, search

So when you're looking for questions, you can filter questions based on a certain tag, by simply writing that tag in the search.

However, can you do the exact opposite of that, i.e, certain tags filtered ***out***? That would be very helpful for me, as I have to scroll pages after pages of the same tag before I can find an answerable question.

Remember, this is different from looking up a certain tag. I can answer questions with every tag *but* a certain one.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24514/how-do-i-combine-exclude-multiple-tags-from-a-search is possibly a better duplicate target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `-` sign before the tag

That is

```
-[tag]
```

If you want to filter some tags and filter out some tags, use this

```
[tag-to-be-included]-[tag-to-be-filtered-out]
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. It always shows: `Could not find any results for - [tag]; showing results for "- [tag]"`

Comment: Don't add space and semi colon `;`

Comment: I didn't add semicolon. But even after removing space, the search automatically adds quotations on either side, and says `your search returned no matches`. Head over to movies and tv stack exchange and try filtering out `identify-this-movie` tag, if you don't believe me. **EDIT**: It only works with one-word tags, not tags with `-` sign in them.

Comment: I tried what you said exactly and it is working perfectly.

Comment: I think you are misreading that `[]` is just a place holder. This is the syntax you should follow. `[identify-this-movie]-[identify-this-tv-show]` likewise. The `[]` is required to search tag @RapidReaders