# Tag search doesn't work properly

Tags: support, bug, tags, search, tag-search

I am trying to do a search on SO where I include a few tags, and exclude a few:

```
[c#] or [java] or [winforms] -[android] -[android-studio]
```

[Link to search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+or+java+or+winforms+-android+-android-studio)

The problem is, questions with the tags `c#`, `java`, and/or `winforms` are included, but questions with the tags `android` and/or `android-studio` are NOT excluded.

Based on what I read in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24516/367306), I should have my excludes before my includes:

```
-[android] -[android-studio] [c#] or [java] or [winforms]
```

However, when I try and execute that search, it automatically reorders it with the includes before the excludes.

Is there something I am doing wrong, or is this a bug/feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add parenthese with spaces to the excluded tags or **OR** block to get the expected result.

```
[c#] or [java] or [winforms] ( -[android] -[android-studio] ) is:question
```

or

```
( [c#] or [java] or [winforms] ) -[android] -[android-studio]
```

It will result the [this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+or+%5Bjava%5D+or+%5Bwinforms%5D+%28+-%5Bandroid%5D+-%5Bandroid-studio%5D+%29)

Advanced searh help page: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching

Comment: That works, thank you! If possible, could you explain why the parentheses are needed? I'm not sure on what the order of operations is for the tag search.

Comment: @zwork Please have a look at [advanced search help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching). In the _OR operator_ they mentioned about the usage of parentheses. You can add parentheses for the *OR* or the excluded tags.