# Search with NOT operator

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exclude specific words in search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19253/exclude-specific-words-in-search)

I'd like the ability to exclude results from my searches, probably with a not operator.

Comment: That is not a bad idea.

Comment: In fact, I've often wondered why search didn't include boolean operators (&&, ||, !, brackets) as standard. Why not add all of these?