# Search operators

Tags: support, tags, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search [tag1] OR [tag2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2)

I would like to search for questions about python OR django (and perhaps even NOT Ruby).

Prior requests:

[Use OR operator in tagged question search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114642/use-or-operator-in-tagged-question-search)

=> I would suggest OR not as a default, but as a possibility. I believe SO's semantics are quite different than Google's semantics.

[Search with NOT operator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70932/search-with-not-operator)

https://stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: Hm, did you check the duplicate? What's the point of copy pasting the names of the close voters there?

Comment: Right, I misread the semantics of the close tag. Can't find the duplicate.

Comment: Check right under the title of the question ;)