# Allow search for the opposite of "user:me"?

Tags: feature-request, search

I want to exclude from my search all the results that would normally come up from searching with `user:me`.  I see from this question: [Exclude specific words in stackoverflow search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19253/exclude-specific-words-in-stackoverflow-search)  that there is no "NOT" operator for searches.

However since there is a "is accepted" and a "not accepted", I think a "not user" option would make perfect sense?

*Example of use expected use:*

It would be added in combination with other filters when searching through a specific tag or topic in order to filter out questions that the user has already answered.  Especially in cases where a user is very active in that tag.

Comment: There isn't a way, but you could turn this into a [feature-request] if you're going to put a bounty on it. It'd be nice to just have a generic NOT operator

Comment: @Michael, I had mentioned the feature request for the NOT operator already. I was thinking this is like the "is accepted" search option, where there should be a "Not user" option.  Anyway, I think you are right so I have changed this to a feature request.

Comment: I don't understand why this would be useful? This is the first time it's ever been requested in 3 years that I know of.

Comment: @Jeff, this is not useful by itself.  But in combination with other filters is where I would use it.  Specifically when I am searching through a specific tag or topic that I spend a lot of time in, I find my results get filled with questions I have already answered.  I would like to eliminate those so I can find questions in that topic that I haven't answered yet.

Answer (score 9):

Ideally, I think we should have option to exclude specific users, same way we can exclude tags.

e.g. `-user:155084 is:a [search]` search term will give all answers on [search](/questions/tagged/search) questions, posted by all users except user with ID of 155084.

So `-user:me` will be a shortcut, using ID of currently logged in user.

Comment: I can’t think of a single case of the need to use any specific user except “mine”. Only if for consistency.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, why not `user:others`?

(This could be extended to some criteria like `user:♦` or `user:10k` although rep/mod status shouldn't state anything useful here I guess)

Comment: Maybe it should be `user:mod` so there is no awkward copy-pasting or Unicode codepoints?

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ Oh come on, where's the point in making stalking your favourite mod _too_ comfortable? :-P